# Make an entire table row all links in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetch data from a URL, and I want a specific column of my table to have all its rows clickable and based on the row you click, it takes you to a new table based on that row, with values from a different URL.

```
function DataInfo() { 
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);  
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const columns = [ 
  { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol" }, 
  { headerName: "Name", field: "name" }, 
  { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry" }  
];  

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/all') 
    .then(res => { return res.json();
    })
    .then (data => { setRowData(data);
    })
}, []);

return ( 
  <div className="DataInfo"> 
    <div 
       className="ag-theme-balham" 
       style={{ 
          height: "300px", 
        width: "600px" 
         }} 
    > 
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columns}  
        rowData={rowData}  
        /> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
)
};
```

I want this column: { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol" } to be the one where all its data is clickable.

But I am trying to make it so that if I click on a particular data from that row, it goes to  a new table that uses another URL and will check to see what row was clicked. I don't know if I should be trying to use NavLink but I also used onClick which has not worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your target by using `cellRenderer` like this:

```
const columns = [
  { 
    headerName: "Symbol", 
    field: "symbol",
    cellRenderer: (params) => {
      return <a href={ params.value } target = "_blank" rel = "noopener"> { params.value } </a>
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name",
  },
  { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry" }
];
```

See more detail in this [document](https://blog.ag-grid.com/adding-hyperlinks-to-the-grid/)